# What does "two polynomials have no zeros in common" mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

The question is

> Given two constant-coefficient operators $A$ and $B$ whose characteristic polynomials have no zeros in common. Let $C=AB$...

What does that mean by "no zeros in common"?

Comment: It means that there is no value which is a zero of both polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

It means that if $A(x) = 0$, then $B(x) \neq 0$, and if $B(x) = 0$, then $A(x) \neq 0$.